# Catching Message Handling Exceptions with the @Exceptionhandler

Tags: axon

I have two application e.g) A, B

A has a Saga
B is just web application

A sent Command messages to B and
B sent exception for that Command to A's Saga and A's Saga received well

and B have a **`@ExceptionHandler`** which I hope to be invoked but it's not working

How can I make them be invoked?

---

## EDIT

this is A application's Saga that sends command messages to B application
and deals with exception which B sent

```
@Saga
public class OrderSaga {

    @Autowired
    private transient CommandGateway commandGateway;

    @StartSaga
    @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "orderId")
    public void handle(CreateOrderEvent evt) {

        String paymentId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        SagaLifecycle.associateWith("paymentId", paymentId);
        commandGateway.send(new CreatedPaymentCommand(paymentId, evt.getUserId(),evt.getFoodPrice())).exceptionally(exp -> {
            System.out.println("got it");
            System.out.println(exp.getMessage());
            return null;
        });
    }

}
```

---

this is B application that throws exception for test

```
@Aggregate
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PaymentAggregate {

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String paymentId;
    private String userId;

    private PaymentStatus status;

    @CommandHandler
    public PaymentAggregate(CreatedPaymentCommand cmd) {

        throw new IllegalStateException("this exception was came from payment aggregates");
        // AggregateLifecycle.apply(new CreatedPaymentEvent(cmd.getPaymentId(),
        // cmd.getUserId(),cmd.getMoney()));
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(resultType = IllegalStateException.class)
    public void error(IllegalStateException exp) {
        System.out.println(exp.getMessage());
    }
    // I want this @ExceptionHandler to be invoked


    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(CreatedPaymentEvent evt) {
        this.paymentId = evt.getPaymentId();
        this.userId = evt.getUserId();
    }

}
```

---

A application catch exception well like below

```
2021-08-24 11:46:43.534  WARN 14244 --- [ault-executor-2] o.a.c.gateway.DefaultCommandGateway      : Command 'com.common.cmd.CreatedPaymentCommand' resulted in org.axonframework.commandhandling.CommandExecutionException(this exception was came from payment aggregates)
got it
this exception was came from payment aggregates
```

but B is not I thought that B's @ExceptionHandler will catch that exception

in short, How can I make B's @ExceptionHandler to be invoked

Comment: Would you perchance be able to share some snippets of your Saga's Event Handler, the Exception Handler, and Command Handler annotated methods? That would give a better idea of what might be going wrong in your application. Also, would you mind providing the versions you're using, and if you have Axon Server set up for messaging/event storage?

Comment: thanks I edited and I'm using default setting for server

Comment: and server version is 4.5.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work right now because the exception is thrown from the constructor of your aggregate.
As you are using a constructor command handler, there is no instance present yet.
And without an instance, Axon Framework cannot spot the `@ExceptionHandler` annotated method you've set up.

This is the only missing point for the exception handlers at this stage. Honestly, the reference guide should be a bit more specific about this. I am sure this will change in the future, though.

There's a different approach for having a command handler that constructs the aggregate *and* that can use the `@ExceptionHandler`: with the `@CreationPolicy` annotation. The reference guide has [this](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/axon-framework-commands/command-handlers#aggregate-command-handler-creation-policy) to say about it, by the way.

Thus, instead of having a constructor command handler, you would set up a regular command handler using the  `AggregateCreationPolicy.ALWAYS`.
That would adjust your sample like so:

```java
@Aggregate
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PaymentAggregate {

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String paymentId;
    private String userId;

    private PaymentStatus status;

    @CommandHandler
    @CreationPolicy(AggregateCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
    public void handle(CreatedPaymentCommand cmd) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("this exception was came from payment aggregates");
        // AggregateLifecycle.apply(new CreatedPaymentEvent(cmd.getPaymentId(),
        // cmd.getUserId(),cmd.getMoney()));
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(resultType = IllegalStateException.class)
    public void error(IllegalStateException exp) {
        System.out.println(exp.getMessage());
    }
    // I want this @ExceptionHandler to be invoked


    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(CreatedPaymentEvent evt) {
        this.paymentId = evt.getPaymentId();
        this.userId = evt.getUserId();
    }

}
```

Please give this a try in your application, @YongD.